# Hyperlink and Text to Facebook Post

Tags: facebook

When I add a hyperlink and an image to a Facebook Post. It looks like the image below. Currently it shows my domain name, title meta tag, and beginning text from my site. Is there a way to control what text Facebook is importing from a website? I have tried a meta description tag but it does not work.

[image: Post Image]

Comment: @CBroe. That question is over 9 years old.

Comment: And yet it still links to the important resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control this with Open Graph Tags. Check out the Facebook docs for detailed information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/#markup

You can test and refresh the tags in the Debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/